# foreach and facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

can someone tell me what seems to be the issue with this

```
       <?php 
      $increment =0;
      foreach($status['comments']['data'] as $user_status_comments_value){?>
```

Im getting a

Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/social/facebook/social/examples/dev.php on line 179

Comment: `var_dump($status);` --- stop guessing, operate with **facts**

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that man.. simple questoin

Comment: Run `var_dump($status);` before the foreach to debug it. It's likely its an object and not purely an array

Comment: @Akshat this is the result from the var_dump   http://pastebin.com/P95pZP6i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to rearrange your code a bit

```
foreach($status['data'] as $statusupdate) {
    $user_status_comments_value = $statusupdate["comments"]
    //Dont forget you would still need to loop through each set of comments
    foreach($user_status_comments_value as $comment) {
        ///$comment["data"] contains a comment
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I see what youre trying to do now. The problem is the output facebook gives is ordered items of the comments are you're extracting something else which is nested within each of the first level of objects in the array.

Comment: Im not sure which pieces of data you want as theres not enough info in your question but if you want the stuff in the "comments" arrays you would need to rearrange the array itself

Comment: @David Morin: do you know how `foreach` works and how to deal with php arrays?

Answer (score 1):

It means `$status['comments']['data']` is not an array.

Comment: No, it’s not – $status does not contain any element on the first level with the key 'comments'. Please get some basic PHP knowledge, dude – you’re not even able to figure out how an array is actually structured :-/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work everyone.. Thanks

Here is the working code

http://pastebin.com/taFgSL7J